# Decrement and increment value?

Tags: c#

I have min and max params:

```
var min = 30;
var max = 35;

var num = 33;
```

Also there is timer with step 100 milliseconds.
On body timer I have code:

```
if (num < max)
{
    // Step 1
    num = num + step;    
}

if (num >= max) 
{
     // Step 2
    num = num - step;
}

if (num <= min) 
{
    num = num + step;
}
```

Problem is that if `num = 34.98` works **step 1** (34.99 + 0,05), then **step 2**. So in this step I get infinity loop. How I can do that if `num > max` then do decrement to `min`?

Comment: what is the value of step? always it be 0.05?

Comment: can u post including the loop?

Comment: `var num = 33;` creates `int num`, are you sure it's equal to `34.98`?

Comment: maybe third if replace with else if ?

Comment: Let me understand the question. If num is greater than max, then you want to start decrementing to min? And vice versa? If so, then all you need to do is ׳step*=-1׳ . Is that what you meant?

Comment: Step of increment and decr is 0.05

Comment: I need do decrement with step 0.05

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do other than just showing code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may use an `else if` for the second `if` (and an `else` for the third)

So you could only enter one condition at each loop.

You could then simplify your code to this (assuming min < max, the right part of the or clause could be removed)

```
if (num < max || num <= min) //remove num <= min and throw an exception if max < min could be also done...
   num += step;
else
   num -= step;
```

which could also be (if min < max)

```
num = num < max 
         ? num + step 
         : num - step;
```

Comment: it works but when I come `max` value I get loop `-+` in one step

Comment: You could add an else if then, or change the condition of your loop

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this *one line* of code :

```
  num += num >= max || num <= min? (step = step*-1) : step;
```

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var min = 31;
        var max = 33;

        double num = 32;

        double step = 0.10;            

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            num += num >= max || num <= min? (step = step * -1) : step;

            Console.Write(num);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
}
```

Output: [LINK](https://i.gyazo.com/e6e2c02c064581330ca3ec394213bd03.gif)

Comment: @Babaev I have provided you with a perfectly working example of code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if`s, use `else if` and `else`

```
if (num < max)
    num = num + step;
else if (num >= max)
    num = num - step;
else
    num = num + step;
```

Then remove redudant `if` (Note that `num < max || num <= min` equals `num < max`)

```
if (num < max)
    num = num + step;
else if (num >= max)
    num = num - step;
```

It could be shorten to `num += num < max ? step : step * -1;`

Answer (score 0):

I have done such:

```
if ((num + step) <= max && flag_d == 0)
            {
                num = num + step;
            }
            else {

                if (num <= min) {
                    flag_d = 0;
                }

                flag_d = 1;
                num = num - step;
            }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a solution or a clarification of the question? If the first, it doesn't look reasonable. You conditionally set `flag_d = 0` and then unconditionally set it to `1`. If the second, edit it in into the question.